# Boolean search on database with 5 million rows, very slow

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

I have a script that when a user searches for "Apples", there is a coloumn with related searches like "Shiny Apples", and "Rotten Apples", etc.

Problem is my searches database has 5,600,000 rows and mysql is lagging very badly.

Here is my code:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT keyword FROM searches WHERE MATCH (keyword) AGAINST ('".mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace('#([\S]+)#', '$1', $title))."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 0,15");
```

This is taking a very long time to process and I have a very active website where searches are getting performed every second, can anybody recommend me some  tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your table have an index (or indices)?

Comment: Um.... That makes the first recommendation very easy: create some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need indexes. I have had some experiences in the past where just by creating indexes we got significant performance gain.

Comment: Thanks, definitely sped it up!

Answer (score 0):

You have to index the columns you look into in order to speed things up. I quit using Mysql's native search just because it sucks. I moved to Lucene, and works like charm